# Как у всех столбцов в DF Pandas увидеть значения min/max не являющихся выбросами

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, статистика

Есть набор DF. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно увидеть у всех столбцов минимальное и максимальное значение не являющиеся выбросами (обведены на скрине)? При вызове метода df.describe() эти данные не вижу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а при построении боксплота там это никак не параметризуется?

Comment: не знаю, просто мне нужно, чтобы у всех фичей было посчитано

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал в итоге вот так:

```
df1 = df.describe()
df1 = df1.T

df1['max_no_outlier'] = df1['75%'] + 1.5*(df1['75%'] - df1['25%'])
df1['min_no_outlier'] = df1['25%'] - 1.5*(df1['75%'] - df1['25%'])
df1
```

не знаю, возможно, можно было и проще..